# Continuity of the gradient on the boundary of a lipschitz domain

Tags: sobolev-spaces, trace-map

I have some question :

Let $\Omega\subset{\mathbb{R^{2}}}$ bounded with lipschitz boundary, assme the function $f$ satisfy : $f\in{W^{2,\infty}(\Omega)}$.

I need to show that :
$\nabla f \in{C^{0}(\partial{\Omega)}}$. That is how i proceed :

Since $f\in{W^{2,\infty}(\Omega)}$ implies  $\nabla f\in{W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)}$ and by the trace theorem : 
$\nabla f\in{W^{\frac{1}{2},\infty}(\partial\Omega)}$
then using  the inclusion :$W^{\frac{1}{2},\infty}(\partial\Omega)\subset C^{m}(\partial\Omega)$ for $ m = k - \frac{N}{p}$ here $k=\frac{1}{2}, N=2, p = \infty$

I deduce that : $\nabla f\in { C ^{0}(\partial\Omega)}$

Question : Is that true ?

Comment: Can you dig up the exact statements of the theorems that you are using? I am suspicious slightly of the use of $p = \infty$ since it is often excluded.

Comment: There is no need to that since we work in bounded domain i.e this is true for all p. and you can take p sufficiently large to get inclusion

Comment: I meant, if you want to be sure that your inlusions are correct, then I would have to know what theorems you are using and since it is often hard to do the finding of theorems on my own given their applications, I was asking if you would do that in my stead.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f\in W^{2,\infty}$, $\nabla f\in W^{1,\infty}$. By Sobolev embedding, this implies $\nabla f \in C(\bar \Omega)$. Hence,  the restriction of $\nabla f$ to the boundary is a continuous function as well.